# Address of stack memory associated with local variable returned (C++)

Tags: c++

Mac OSX, I'm trying to use tchar.h, but apparently that's Windows specific. And I'm guessing it is the reason this code is not working for me:

```
//toString

char *Node::toString(){

    char hilera[100];
    strcpy(hilera, dato->toString());
    strcat(hilera, "\n");
    return hilera;


}
```

So, what do you suggest?

Comment: What about your code doesn't work?

Comment: You don't appear to be trying to use `tchar.h`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After exit from function-scope `hilera` will be destroyed, dangling pointer will be returned. Use `std::string`, or allocate memory in heap.

Comment: +1 for `std::string`--there's no good reason to pass around C strings if your code is C++ (interoperability with C APIs notwithstanding...)

Answer (score 4):

The reason the code is not working is that it is returning the address of a local variable, which is undefined behaviour. You need to dynamically allocate a buffer and return it's address. Or as this is C++ return a `std::string` instead.

Comment: It must be C++, since C doesn't have member functions nor namespaces.

Comment: @MooingDuck, do'h ! Was concentrating on the implementation of the function.